# Text inside <p> shrinks on mobile devices while div does not

Tags: mobile, browser, xhtml

Does anybody know whats happening here? I tested on opera, dolphin and the factory android browser. (although it seems now to be working on opera)

The div doesn't change size, but the text somehow is shrunk to fit on part of a div.
Anyway to prevent this?

Just to be clear, I'm trying to achieve on the mobile browser the same look as the pc version.

As the problem seems to be with the browsers, how can I force the text to take the full width of the div? I tried setting the p tag to 100% with no success.

The div has to have that width and be aligned to the left of the page.

***Update 1:** I tried the following code on a galaxy s4 (previously tried on s2) and got the same error on opera mini and dolphin.
The error can be visualized online using the [opera mini simulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/opera-mini-simulator), you just need to host the html file somewhere.

***Update 2:** I believe the problem exists because when the webpage is loaded, it is loaded at its normal size (pixels), so the paragraph only occupies a small part of the page. Then, the page zooms out so all the content fits the page, but the text does not spread, it stays in that initial small space.

[image]

On a Pc, as it should be:

[image]

I shrunk the code as much as I could:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-us">
<head>

<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />

<meta content="" name="keywords" />
<meta content="" name="description" />

<title></title>

</head>
<body>
<div style="width:1000px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" >

<div style="float:left; width:758px; background-color:aqua;">
<p>

Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text 
Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text 
Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text  
Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text  
Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text  
Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text  
Random text Random text .
<br />
<br />
Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text  
Random text Random text Random text .
<br />
<br />
Random text Random text Random text Random text  
<a href="http://www.a.com/a.html">
Random text </a> Random text  
Random text .
</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The above code works fine for me on Safari Mobile and Android Browser.

Comment: @MattCoughlin Thanks Matt. I should've said that I tried that code on android.

Comment: Tried on iPad2 and Android 2.3 stock browser (Motorola Droid2 Global), without issue. Which borwsers are you using? Don't they have some exotic plugin installed?

Comment: @ern0 No plugins. Stock android, dolphin, opera mini. It does work on opera and chrome. Try zooming out to make sure it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Better start applying HTML5, and the proper doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Then tune the viewport, so it can be applied:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I don't have Opera Mini to test, but according to the compatibility table it should be working.

Comment: The link is up on my question, just click on "opera mini". thanks for the answer, but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

The mobile web browser scales the page automatically so that the user can see the text more clearly. If you want to prevent the text from scaling, add this code in the `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

To your page.

Here is a good read about the viewport meta tag: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag/

Comment: I will research this a bit more. I tried it, and it zooms in where the content is, so initially I don't see the blank space, but there's a scroll bar at the bottom. Simply zooming out, I can then see that the blank portion of the div is still there. And that's a problem for me, I have content after that div.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a text zoom thing in Webkit try adding the css:

- { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; }

or

- { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; }

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem nearly identical to this on Droid Razr (Droid OS 4.1.2) - stock browser. It turned out to be a problem with the browser itself - corrupted settings or something. **Going to Settings > Advanced > Reset to Default > OK** fixed the problem.

Comment: No quite what happened here, but you are right, on opera, there's an option called "wrapping text" that when changed to no changes the result and on dolphin its called "auto fit content". So that does confirm the problem being with the browsers, how can I make sure the content is delivered to 100% of the page?

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I use

```
text-align: center;
```

everything is OK, but when I use

```
text-align: left;
```

text is shrunk (Android 4.1 browser)

Need to research a bit more...

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the widths in relative units like %.

as here:

**width:100%; for first div and..**

**width:75%; for the div inside it**

Comment: Works on opera, stock android and chrome, but not on dolphin